# Why does scikit gaussian process whitekernel give the following output?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

[The docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.WhiteKernel.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.WhiteKernel) for this kernel say that:

k(x_1, x_2) = noise_level if x_1 == x_2 else 0

Which makes sense.  However, when I attempt to verify this thing, it does not seem to be the case:

```
>>> sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.WhiteKernel(noise_level=2)(np.array([[1,1]]),np.array([[1,1]]))
array([[0.]])
```

What am I missing here?

PS, if the second arg is not provided, it evaluates K(X,X), which gives the expected output

```
>>> sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.WhiteKernel(noise_level=2)(np.array([[1,1]]))
array([[2.]])
```

Comment: I've just ran over the same problem years after your post. Indeed, with a X _and_ a Y supplied to `__call__` , `np.zeros((_num_samples(X), _num_samples(Y)))` is returned. But I believe a check of identical rows between X and Y must be performed instead. I guess it assumes that no samples between X and Y are the same, which is Wierd. Cyril